# Revert keyword in solidity

Tags: solidity, evm

I've deployed contract in ropsten test net with this source code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.15;

    contract C{

        function throws(){
            throw;
        }
        function reverts(){
            revert();
        }
        function requires(){
            require(false);
        }
        function asserts(){
            assert(false);
        }
    }
```

As I expected calling `reverts()` function should return me all gas. But this doesn't work and all I've paid a lot of ether for this failed transaction (https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x2084cc38b1695d52448a7cf5c887ca1ea3f82163491cc48c18e8987e6e9defed)

Can someone explain me how it's possible please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

revert only refunds **unused gas** . You can test this by setting a high gas limit 3000000 for example and calling the asserts and reverts methods of your contract, you'll see that asserts consumes all of the gas limit, where as reverts returns unconsumed gas

Comment: Thanks! Also this article (https://media.consensys.net/ethereum-gas-fuel-and-fees-3333e17fe1dc) says that maximum amount of refundable gas is the half of amount of gas which was already consumed.